# Showing/Hiding variable-height panels with CSS transitions not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a section of my HTML that shows one "pane" at a time.  These "panes" vary in height.  I have a button that - when clicked - hides one pane and shows another.  What I'm trying to do is make this a smooth transition without any jerkiness using CSS only.  If the pane is smaller or larger than its container, the container should smoothly collapse or expand to suit the required height of the new pane.

I have the following so far:

**JS:**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#get-started").addClass("hiddenFade");
  $("#get-started-2").removeClass("hiddenFade");
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

<div id="get-started" class="box fadeInOut">
  TEST
</div>
<div id="get-started-2" class="box fadeInOut hiddenFade">
  NEWTEST
</div>
</div>
<button>
  go
</button>
```

**LESS:**

```
.box{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}  

.container{
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 400px;
  margin:auto;
}

.fadeInOut {
        transition-duration: 0, 200ms;
        transition-property: visibility, opacity, height;
        transition-delay: 0;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 1; 

        &.hiddenFade {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            transition-duration: 200ms, 0;
            transition-property: opacity, visibility, height;
            transition-delay: 0, 200ms;
            height: 0 !important;
        }
    }

#get-started-2{
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

However none of the transitions appear to be working.  What am I doing wrong?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxPXZv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `transition-...` properties you have to specify a measuring unit even when you use `0`.

```
transition-duration: 0ms, 200ms;
```

instead of

```
transition-duration: 0, 200ms;
```

The same goes for `transition-delay`.

After addressing that, it seems to work as expected:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#get-started, #get-started-2").toggleClass("hiddenFade");
})
```

```css
.box{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}  

.container{
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 400px;
  margin:auto;
}

.fadeInOut {
        transition-duration: 0ms, 200ms;
        transition-property: visibility, opacity, height;
        transition-delay: 0ms;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 1; 
}
        .fadeInOut.hiddenFade {
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            transition-duration: 200ms, 0ms;
            transition-property: opacity, visibility, height;
            transition-delay: 0ms, 200ms;
            height: 0 !important;
        }
    

#get-started-2{
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<div id="get-started" class="box fadeInOut">
  TEST
</div>
<div id="get-started-2" class="box fadeInOut hiddenFade">
  NEWTEST
</div>
</div>
<button>
  go
</button>
```